# how to change color of progress bar kivy

Tags: python, progress-bar, kivy

I am new in kivy i can not add customise colour on progress bar kivy please help me to implement this

```
 ProgressBar:
                    id: pb
                    size_hint:dp(.9),dp(.4)
                    background_color:"#22222" 
                    #value: (app.time * 20) % 100.
                    value: 50
                    pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top": .65}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`BorderImage`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.BorderImage) and change the `source`.

There is no attribute, `background_color` for `ProgressBar`. It uses BorderImages. The first `BorderImage` (e.g. blue.png) acts as a rail/track whereby the second `BorderImage` (e.g. red.png) runs on the rail/track.

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Rootwidget>:
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        max: 1000

        canvas:
            BorderImage:
                border: (12, 12, 12, 12)
                pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
                size: self.width, 24
                source: 'blue.png'
            BorderImage:
                border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 12))] * 4
                pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
                size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 24
                source: 'red.png'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: it does not change the bar it change background of progressbar

Comment: Is your question regarding changing the background color or the bar?